# Blender is deleting half of my video

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

So I wanted to record a timelapse of me doing something in Blender and then edit said video in the same software; but I am having a really weird issue every time I try to put the video into the editor. The video gets cut off exactly half way through. It's not just that it **says** that it's twice as short, it's that it **is** twice short. The second half of the video just doesn't exist in the editor no matter how much I play with the settings, (including fps) although it seems to keep all of the sound intact for whatever reason.

(I didn't want to upload a picture/gif because I don't even know what I'd show)

Is there something I'm missing here, like a video size cap or am I just being silly?

Note: This only happens with this particular video, all others do not have the same problem.

Comment: does the frame length in blender match the frames in your video?

Comment: Your media frame rate is double the Blender project value OR your media is frame segmented HD (interlaced frames). If its from an AVCHD codec like a Sony camera you will have to transcode it to something Blender recognises.

Comment: There seems to be exactly half as many frames in Blender as in the file. 
The video is at 29 fps, setting that in Blender yields no results. 3pointedit  could you elaborate more on that? I used the built in Wind 10 recording software.